# How to query times added to issue in GitLab since a specific date for a user?

Tags: gitlab

I would like to query how much a colleague worked since a date, but without manually loop all the issues and cumulate, calculate total times spent since reference date. Is it possible in GitLab?

Comment: what do you mean by "cumulate times"? do you mean what's in the estimated work time field?

Comment: calculate total times